# mariadb-test / mysqltest: symbol lookup error: mariadb-test: undefined symbol: PCRE2regcomp

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian

I'm trying to fine tune my database and for that I would like to try the mariadb-test (or mysqltest) client program.
I've trying installing it a few times, via apt (which I updated), downloading the package and installing with dpkg but I always run into this error:

```
mysqltest: symbol lookup error: mysqltest: undefined symbol: PCRE2regcomp
```

I understand that there must be an error with dependencies, but I don't know how to solve it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

---

Environment:

- Debian buster
- MariaDB 10.5.12
- Nginx 1.18

---

```
ldd /usr/bin/mysqltest
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd6dce5000)
    libpcre2-posix.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-posix.so.2 (0x00007f02e00cf000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f02e003c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f02e001b000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f02dff89000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f02dfc9d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f02dfc98000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f02dfa78000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f02df8f4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f02df771000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f02df5b0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f02e0524000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f02df596000)
```

---

EDIT:

Ok, now it's getting weird. I created a virtual machine with a fresh debian install, installed mariadb-server-10.5 according to [this](https://kifarunix.com/install-mariadb-10-5-on-debian-10-buster/#install-mariadb-10.5-from-apt-repos), installed mariadb-test from apt and got it worked.
Then I replicated in the server, removed the old repository from the apt/sources.list, added the one according to the link, uninstalled mariadb-test and related pcre libraries and reinstalled mariadb-test from apt.

Same error.

ldd /bin/mariadb-test outputs the same in both machines (except for the hexadecimals).

So at this point I'm not sure that the issue is with packages, but don't really know what to try next.

Comment: if its the debian package, report to bugs.debian.org. If its the MariaDB distributed package report to jira.mariadb.org.

Comment: Hi @danblack, thanks for your comment. I was reporting the bug on debien when it alerted me that buster comes with mariadb 10.3, not 10.5. So it's not a debian package issue. But since I was able to get mariadb-test to work on a fresh install, I don't think it's MariaDB packages issue as well. Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Debian and MariaDB packages installed [mariadb-test in /usr/bin](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/mariadb-test/filelist).

This looks like maybe a binary tarball that has been installed into / with --skip-prefix=1. The missing symbol is because it was linked again pcre version 1 rather than version 2.

Its also a distribution bug as binary tarballs should have been [statically linked](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26265).

Comment: Thanks again for looking into this @danblack. Do you have any suggestion on how I could fix it? Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: This looks like a messed up pcre2 compiled version on your system. The only reference to PCRE2regcomp I've seen is in the readme of https://github.com/luvit/pcre2, as a optional compile option. mariadb-test is about functional testing of the MariaDB server. It actually won't help you with tuning. Ask a tuning question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ with your config and `show global status` output.